# Математическая формула в С++

Tags: c++, математика, циклы, ряды

Стоит задача

> Создать приложение с помощью которого можно для ряда, члены которого
>   вычисляются по формуле
>   подсчитать сумму членов ряда с точностью до 0,000001 и сумму первых 10
>   членов ряда.

Вот сама формула:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Написал такой код:

```
int n = 1;
        double a = 1, sum = 0.0, eps = 0.000001, sum_of_10 = 0;
        while (fabs(a) > 0.000001) {
            a = pow(-1, n)*((double)(2 * (n + 1)) / (2 + (n+1) * (n-1)));
            sum += a;
            if (n == 10)
                sum_of_10 = sum;
            n++;
        }
        textBox1->Text = sum_of_10.ToString();
```

Когда нажимаю на кнопку на форме чтобы это всё посчитало то форму фризит и она зависает

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я сделал не так?

Comment: Такие вопросы обычно решаются отладкой.

Comment: Я только учусь и как проводить отладку совсем не знаю)

Comment: В случаях с бесконечным циклом - можно ставить блок бесконечного цикла счётчиком в теле цикла. Например так `if (anti++ > 1000000) break;` это ухудшит результат, но уберёт повисание.

Comment: Какая-то странная запись - (-1<sup>n</sup>)? а не (-1)<sup>n</sup>. Тут нет ошибки?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Прикиньте - у вас нужно порядка миллиона членов. Так? А чему будет равно `(n+1) * (n-1)` при этом? В `double` преобразование вы делаете позже... Вот ваши 10<sup>12</sup> никак и не хотят в `int` влезть... Соответственно, *a* не хочет становиться малым - вот и имеем то, что имеем - бесконечный цикл.

Сделайте хотя бы так:

```
int n = 1;
double a = 1, sum = 0.0, eps = 0.000001, sum_of_10 = 0.0, sign = 1;
while (fabs(a) > eps)
{
    sum += (a = (sign *= -1)*(2.0*(n + 1))/(1.0+double(n)*n));
    if (n == 10) sum_of_10 = sum;
    n++;

}
```

> Я только учусь и как проводить отладку совсем не знаю

Ну хотя бы выводить промежуточные результаты можете? Скажем, для каждого тысячного n вывести a<sub>n</sub> и посмотреть, что получается?

И еще - такие медленно сходящиеся ряды лучше считать с конца, начиная с мелких значений слагаемых - так точность будет более высокой. Для вашего примера и вашей точности это не так важно, но приобретать хорошие манеры :) имеет смысл с самого начала.

Comment: Понял принял, благодарю всё работает, буду учить)